# Display data from excel in a web page

Tags: database, excel, html, dashboard

I am a complete newbie when it comes to web page design, and what I am trying to achieve is a web page that I can display on a wall mounted screen as an office dashboard.  I have data in excel that is constantly being updated (on the server) and I want to be able summarise this and display it (e.g. total orders etc.) for staff to see.  Therefore the web page needs to be able to connect to the data source, and update itself every few minutes.  I am hoping to then use Ubuntu or even Raspberry Pi to drive the dashboards.

Can anybody point me towards either some clear instruction on how to achieve this, or better still some sample files that will help me see how its done?

Really appreciate any help!!

Comment: This is a very broad question. Have you thought about a concrete technology? Do you have any experience creating web apps?

Comment: Apologies, I'm wondering what you are referring to as a "concrete technology"....?

Comment: Technologies such as PHP, Python, Ruby... whatever you were planning to use. If you are not familiar with any technology that might be a candidate, sample files will not be of much use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP, you can use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md), to read your Excel files, and if you want to only display the information as is, you may [output it to HTML directly](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md), there is an API to manipulate the Excel file, so you may use that to summarize your data, however, if you need something cleaner, you may want to use Windows instead of Linux, given that in Windows, you can use an Excel file as a data source, and there are third party products that can use them as if it were a database (using SQL queries to retrieve data).